# jquery slide show able to run on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, slideshow

I'm trying to write slide show on jquery which is able to run on Internet Explorer 8.
[Here I attached sample to download](http://orion.mn/slideshow_IE8_1.rar).
it runs fine, but I want to start from different image based on the day of month.
For example, when it's 23rd Aug, then slide show must start from the 23rd image.
It is no problem if IE9 or higher, but in IE8, I can't find any solution.
Unfortunately, here in Mongolia, almost half of all computers still have IE8.
Please help me!!!
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

also sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 265px; width: 120px; margin: 0px}
.slideshow img { padding: 0px; border: 0px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
body {
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
}
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideIndex = 1, delay = 14, delayHandle = 0;
var slides = $('.slideshow');
var imgCount = 3;
var today = new Date();
slideIndex = parseInt(today.getDate());
slideIndex = slideIndex % imgCount;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 100,
        timeout: 5000
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <a href="http://www.orion.mn/ach-ur.html" class="customfont_menu" target="_blank">
            <img src="reclampanel_slideshow/pic1.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.orion.mn/ach-ur.html" class="customfont_menu" target="_blank">
            <img src="reclampanel_slideshow/pic2.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.orion.mn/ach-ur.html" class="customfont_menu" target="_blank">
            <img src="reclampanel_slideshow/pic3.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Orgil

Comment: We are not going to unrar (I cannot even unrar) your files. Please post a [mcve] HERE, preferably using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Also I do not even know anyone with an IE8 - MS ended the support for this ancient browser on January 12, 2016

Comment: thanks for comment, i edited the post changed the link.

Comment: So I guess the place it could fail is in cycle.js. Any console errors? There is nothing in the script I see on the screen that would obviously fail in IE8 and you are using an ancient jQuery too

Comment: this sample works fine, only I cant start from specific image. Image number to start is var slideIndex. But i cant use it

Comment: No need to parseInt an int

Comment: So `var slideIndex = new Date().getDate()% $(".slideshow img").length`

Comment: then how to use slideIndex as starting number to start slide from

Comment: I cannot guess why that does not work. You need to debug the slideshow code and see why it ignores the setting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220298/discussion-between-orgil-and-mplungjan).

Comment: How do you use the `slideIndex` in IE 11? Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console in IE 8? I think you can refer to the **Automatic Slideshow** section in [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) about how to use  `slideIndex` in slideshow.